# How do I interpret motion values for bowguns

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I am new to the Monster Hunter series and have recently been trying to understand the game mechanics a little deeper.

I just learned from [this excellent Gaijin Hunter's article](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/73946102476/mh4-how-damage-calculation-works-simplified) about "damage calculation" in Monster Hunter. However, I am confused about motion values when it comes to bowguns.

According to the article, the motion value of an attack in the percentage of the weapon's power (which has to be calculated too) dealt as damage by the said attack. So, if a weapon's power is 100 and the motion value of an attack is 20, then the attack will deal 20 damage (without taking other important factors into consideration).

As a Light Bowgun mainer, I looked for the motion values for the weapon's various shots (that you can find [here](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/92814625497/mh4-understanding-motion-values) along with motion values for all other weapons) and did not know how to interpret what I saw.

An example is:

Normal LV1: 6x1

I am thinking that the "6" means that each normal shot lv1 deals 6% of the weapon's power as damage, but what about the "x1"?

It even gets more complex with others like:

Crag Lv1: 25+30 fire x 3

Normal LV3: 10x1+x (shrapnel)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't think that's an accurate depiction of crag shot damage (crags only have one explosion and deal separate values for several different types of damage at once) and would recommend this document for damage info instead: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wdNS7nJMHRih_Wj55LhTkZOhISqxOODmN2aRvM-OCBM/edit

Comment: @AndrewGorcester thank you very much. Will take a look at the document right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some shots, like Normal S2 or Pierce S 1/2/3 can deal damage to the target multiple times. The "xN" just indicates how many times this shot can deal damage. I'll illustrate with some examples.

For Normal S1, you only fire one pellet which deals damage once, and it has a motion value (MV) per hit of 6, so the total damage is is 6x1.

Crag shots have a MV 25 raw damage from the pellet hitting, and then a MV of 30 for each explosion (which deals fire damage). There are 3 explosions, so this fire damage is applied 3 times. So the total MV becomes 25 + 30firex3.

Comment: I've avoided commenting on Normal S3 until I do some further research. His Normal S3 MV seems to be wrong, but it's possible Normal S3 has changed drastically since MH3U.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. He stated in his article that finding motion values was not rocket science and required a lot of working like "kicking monsters" and he acknowledged that some of the motion values could be wrong. But "assuming the information is correct" (even though it might now, as you said), would I interpret the "+x" as the additional motion value of sharpnel?

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Yes, if it's correct I would assume the "+x" means that every additional time the Normal S3 hits, it does 1 more damage. In previous games the MV was: 10xH, where H is how many times it hit. So if his MV is right,  then Normal S3 is a *lot* weaker in MH4U compared to previous games.

Comment: Oh, now I understand why you are skeptical about this motion value. It makes sense. So, mathematically, I think it should be "10 x (1 + x)" with the parentheses if my understanding is correct. Thank you once again for your detailed answers.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Ah you know what, I bet that's *exactly* what gajin meant. Bracket placement is important!

Comment: I thought I would share this with you. It's about the MV for the Normal LV3 shots. In [Gaijin Hunter's LBG tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kGgyfwObSg) (at 05:00) he explains that the MV is indeed 10x1 but has "the ability to bounce off very large monsters for extra hits (sharpnel)".

Comment: You're very welcome.